# Is writing to a file using std::ofstream slower than using std::cout and then redirecting that output to a log file

Tags: c++

I can write data to a file using

```
std::ofstream fileStream;
fileStream << "Some Data";
```

or simply do a

```
std::cout << "Some Data";
```

and do `./myBinary > outFile`

Which one is faster ?

Comment: It would be fairly easy to test this, no?

Comment: Imagine yourself: `program >> file` versus `program >> terminal >> file`. Anyway, you should design your program properly according to your requirements (maybe you implement both features)

Comment: @DieterLücking I don't think this is accurate. To my knowledge, redirection causes the stdout handle to be *replaced* with a file handle. For example, if you do `./program < file` then you can `fstat(stdin)` in order to see the size of the input file.

Comment: @cdhowie I'am not sure, but I cant think of a (terminal redirected) file handle which is not provided by a terminal (directed through the terminal).

Comment: @DieterLücking A simple test I've done confirms my argument.  I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be significantly slower, and in fact the performance difference (if there even is any!) will be negligible.

Redirection causes the standard output / input / error handles to be *replaced* with a handle directly to the given file.  As long as there are not needless flushes of the output stream, performance should be nearly identical, if not exactly identical.  (I would hope that `std::cin` is able to detect whether or not output is to a terminal, and disable automatic flushing on `std::endl` if it is not.)

To prove this, let's take this small C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct stat s;

    fstat(fileno(stdout), &s);

    fprintf(stderr, "Output is file? %d\n", S_ISREG(s.st_mode));

    return 0;
}
```

And run it in a few situations:

```
chris@onslow:~$ ./testbin
Output is file? 0
chris@onslow:~$ ./testbin >/dev/null
Output is file? 0
chris@onslow:~$ ./testbin >foo
Output is file? 1
```

With a similar program that calls `fstat()` on standard input, we can see that the program can determine the size of the input file, indicating that it has a handle *directly to the file* and not some intermediate pipe:

```
chris@onslow:~$ ./testbin
Input file size is 0
chris@onslow:~$ ./testbin < /dev/null
Input file size is 0
chris@onslow:~$ echo hello > foo
chris@onslow:~$ ./testbin < foo
Input file size is 6
```

Comment: You might be right: `program > file` is altering the stdout handle in the program environment.

Comment: @DieterLücking It's worth noting that shell piping (`program | otherprogram`) just creates a unidirectional pipe and replaces standard output of `program` with the write-only end, and standard input of `otherprogram` with the read-only end. So even in that case it's not going through the shell, but rather through the kernel.